# Render Google Map in Laravel Voyager admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

i am trying to show google map in Voyager admin panel i use bread but i get error :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: path\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\formfields\coordinates.blade.php) (View: paht\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\formfields\coordinates.blade.php)
```

any solution ?

Comment: Please Read [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add trait Spatial in your model

use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Spatial;

and initialize the field with coordinates

```
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Spatial;

class Product extends Model
{
  use Spatial;
  protected $spatial = ['coordinates']; //here is going your field name; should be the point type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why there is a clear documentation for this awesome Voyager!